# How to use templates inside templates in helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I want to use template inside template with "." operator in my helm chart.

Suppose this is my values.yaml

```
component: my-component
my-component-arguments:
  heap_opts: "heap-opts"
```

Now I want to get "heap_opts", but component name is dynamic.
How can I do something like this using template?

```
{{ .Values."{{.Values.component}}-arguments".heap_opts }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [get](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html)  spring function combined with [index and printf](https://godoc.org/text/template#hdr-Functions) from `text/template` package

```yaml
{{ get (index .Values (printf "%s-arguments" .Values.component)) "heap_opts" }}
```